# rewriting subdomains with the full url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

i would like to redirect 3 different urls, all in one htaccess file. But at the moment it isn't working and only the first rule is always triggered.

I would like to redirect the following:

1. service.abc.info to www.abc.de
2. service.abc.info/feedback/abc/ to feedback.abc.info/abc/
3. service.abc.info/feedback/def/ to feedback.abc.info/def/

For 2. and 3. I also need to redirect the complete Request URI.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.abc\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.abc.de [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.abc\.info/feedback/abc/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://feedback.abc.info/abc/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.abc\.info/feedback/def/$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://feedback.abc.info/def/{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable holds the contents of the **Host:** request header, which just contains a hostname. No URI paths. You'll need to match the paths in the pattern of the rewrite rule, additionally, since the first rule is a superset of the other two, you need to move that to the end.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.abc\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?feedback/abc/(.*)$ http://feedback.abc.info/abc/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.abc\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?feedback/def/(.*)$ http://feedback.abc.info/def/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^service\.abc\.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```